# Testcafe tests are not executed on MacBook Big Sur with UnableToAccessScreenRecordingAPIError:

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Testcafe basic test execution failed with an error on MachBook Air 11.6.3 (20G405) even after setting the permission for screen recording.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a basic test
2. Run the test from the command line

`testcafe chrome -e test_suite/tests/temp_test.ts`

3. It prompts for permission to record the screen

[image]
4. Provide the required permission

[image]

Following error is thrown even after giving the permission.

```
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
TestCafe requires permission to record the screen. Open 'System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Screen Recording' and check 'TestCafe Browser Tools' in the application list.

Press any key to retry.
ERROR UnableToAccessScreenRecordingAPIError: The find-window process cannot access the Screen Recording API.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://testcafe.io/403664/release-notes/framework/2021-12-22-testcafe-v1-18-0-released#testcafe-browser-tools-macos-permission-fix) guide in the TestCafe documentation. It describes how to solve the permission issue on macOS.

Comment: Thanks @aleks-pro. Followed the instructions in the documentation. I was able to launch the browsers and run the tests successfully.

Comment: NOTE :  I was able to run the TestCafe Studio without any issue (prior to the configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the .testcafe-browser-tools folder from your home directory. If this does not help, try executing the following command:

```
chmod +x "/Users/{​​user}​​/.testcafe-browser-tools/TestCafe Browser Tools.app/Contents/MacOS/testcafe-browser-tools"
```

Also, if you are using the M1 chip, try installing Rosetta 2. If the problem still persists,  i suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&template=bug_report.yaml) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and add a sample project and a video to demonstrate how you reproduce it. Make sure that the callstack with the problem is also visible.

Comment: 1. Removed the `.testcafe-browser-tools` folder 2. Changed the permission 3. I am not using M1 chip, using Intel. BTW this worked well with TestCafe Studio. My trial is expired and want to switch to VS code for sometime.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me:

1. Start TestCafe
2. Get the "TestCafe requires permission" error
3. Remove TestCafe Browser Tools from MacOS Security list (by clicking "minus" icon). Save.
4. Cmd+C to abort the command.
5. Start TestCafe again.
6. Open Security list again and grant the permission.
7. Press any key